# How can I convert to lambda with my Custom Class?

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

I use Kotlin and practice lambda expression.

In normal, `View.setOnClickListener` can convert to lambda

Normal

```
textView.setOnClickListener(object :View.OnClickListener{
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {

    }
})
```

Lambda

```
textView.setOnClickListener { }
```

then I copy the source code and just rename the function

```
class CustomView{

    fun setCustomOnClickListener(l: CustomOnClickListener) {
        throw RuntimeException("Stub!")
    }

}

interface CustomOnClickListener {
    fun customOnClick(var1: View?)
}
```

and I create my customView but it can't be convert to lambda

```
      val myCustomView = CustomView()

      myCustomView.setCustomOnClickListener(object :CustomOnClickListener{

          override fun customOnClick(var1: View?) {

          }
      })

  //  can't convert to 
  //  myCustomView.setCustomOnClickListener{
  //
  //  }
```

Can anyone explains why and how to convert to lambda expression?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking about is called a SAM conversion (converting an actual interface implementation into a lambda). SAM stands for "single abstract method."

You can only do SAM conversions for Java interfaces (which `View.OnClickListener` is). But your `CustomOnClickListener` is a Kotlin interface. Therefore, you cannot do a SAM conversion. You *must* implement it with `object : CustomOnClickListener { override . . . }`. You cannot use a lambda.

Straight from the [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions):

> note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported

What you could do if you wanted to keep your code concise is, instead of creating `interface CustomOnClickListener` you could do

`typealias CustomOnClickListener = (View?)->Unit`

then your setter function would be the same. Your invoking function would then be `this.myListener(myView)`

or you could even use the experimental inline class instead:

`inline class CustomOnClickListener(val customOnClick: (View?)->Unit)`

then your setter would be

`fun setListener(listener: CustomOnClickListener) { this.listener = listener }`

and your invoking code would be

`listener.customOnClick(someView)`

**Edit** Some more fleshed-out code:

```
class CustomView{
    var listener: CustomOnClickListener? = null

    fun setCustomOnClickListener(l: CustomOnClickListener) {
        listener = l
    }

}
```

And then you can do this:

```
inline class CustomOnClickListener(val customOnClick: (View?)->Unit)
```

and then your custom view:

```
val myCustomView = CustomView()

myCustomView.setCustomOnClickListener(CustomOnClickListener({ it: View? ->
    // whatever your listener is supposed to do with the view, it goes here
}))
```

Or, instead of `inline class` (which is still considered an experimental feature in Kotlin), you can do this:

```
typealias CustomOnClickListener = (View?)->Unit
```

and then your custom view:

```
val myCustomView = CustomView()

myCustomView.setCustomOnClickListener { it: View? ->
    // whatever your listener is supposed to do with the view, it goes here
}
```

[Here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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) is an example.

Comment: Sorry bro, I can't make sense. Could you post the whole file? Thanks!

Comment: @GuanHongHuang I added a link to an example.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @user1713450 said, this concept is called [SAM Conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) and this works for only Java interop; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported.

To explain your code above:

The `object` keyword can be used to create objects of an anonymous class known as anonymous objects. They are used if you need to create an object of a slight modification of some class or interface without declaring a subclass for it.

The correct syntax should be:

```
interface CustomOnClickListener {

fun customOnClick(var1: View?)

}

//Use the interface in your class
class CustomView{

fun setCustomOnClickListener(l: CustomOnClickListener) {
    throw RuntimeException("Stub!")

  }

}
```

To use the `CustomView` class:

```
val customView = CustomView()

  customView.setCustomOnClickListener(object: CustomOnClickListener{

      override fun customOnClick(var1: View?) {

      }
  })
```

Comment: This can't compile.It show the error "This class does not have a constructor.

Comment: @huang12345 sorry for the error, try this now. I just edited it.

Comment: Sorry bro, but what is your code different from mine?

Comment: @huang12345 You need to call `setCustomOnClikcListener` on the instance of your CustomView class i.e. `customView` not `myCustomView`.

Comment: I did it, but still can't convert to lambda :(

Comment: Just like @user1713450 said, you can't convert it into a lambda because it is a Kotlin Interface and not Java. I should have made it clear in my answer. I was only correcting your code  :)

Answer (score 0):

I have converted spinner's OnItemSelectedListener using lambda function as parameter
check it out where I only care about onItemSelected method.

```
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView

class SelectionListener(val lis:(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) -> Unit) : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


  override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

    lis(parent,view, position, id)

  }

  override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) { }

}
```

Now attach it to your spinner in activity / fragment

```
my_spinner.onItemSelectedListener = SelectionListener { parent, view, position, id ->
//do your work after selection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think as of the date this question was posted, it wasn't possible to do so in Kotlin. But now it's available in Kotlin starting from version 1.4 with functional interfaces.

Here is an example on how to do it:

```
// Define your interface here (note the 'fun' modifier prior to 'interface')
fun interface CustomOnClickListener {
    fun customOnClick(view: View)
}

// Call your custom interface in the form of a Lambda
myCustomView.setCustomOnClickListener { view ->
    // Implement your logic here
}
```

For more information about functional interfaces, you can visit the following link https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#sam-conversions